# sonar "measure filter as treemap" color shows Grey boxes instead of green

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube-scan

I configured myproject(maven) on Sonar.I create a 'TreeMap' and set the 'colorMetric' as 'Coverage'.  I found that only grey boxes appears there (no colored boxes). 
Is there any thing wrong with my configurations?

Here is my sonar.properties file:

> sonar.projectKey=com.company:myproject sonar.projectName=myproject
>   sonar.projectVersion=1.0 sonar.language=java
>   sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
>   sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
>
> sonar.modules= analysis,api,re,web,functional-testing,oasisengine,core
>
> analysis.sonar.sources=src/main analysis.sonar.tests=src/test
>   analysis.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   analysis.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   analysis.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   analysis.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> api.sonar.projectBaseDir=api api.sonar.sources=src/main
>   api.sonar.tests=src/test api.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   api.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   api.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   api.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> re.sonar.projectBaseDir=re re.sonar.sources=src/main
>   re.sonar.tests=src/test re.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   re.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   re.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   re.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> web.sonar. projectBaseDir=web web.sonar.sources=src/main
>   web.sonar.tests=src/test web.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   web.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   web.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> functional-testing. sonar.projectBaseDir=functional-testing
>   functional-testing.sonar.sources=src/main
>   functional-testing.sonar.tests=src/test
>   functional-testing.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   functional-testing.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   functional-testing.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   functional-testing.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> oasisengine. sonar.projectBaseDir=oasisengine
>   oasisengine.sonar.sources=src/main oasisengine.sonar.tests=src/test
>   oasisengine.sonar.binaries=target/classes
>   oasisengine.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   oasisengine.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
>   oasisengine.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
>
> core. sonar.projectBaseDir=core core.sonar.sources=content/src/main
>   core.sonar.tests=content/src/test
>   core.sonar.binaries=content/target/classes
>   core.sonar.junit.reportsPath=content/target/surefire-reports
>   core.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=content/target/surefire-reports
>   core.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=content/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml

Comment: Hi@Auguste,I don't find any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The grey color indicates that no code coverage was found.

The fact that you're analyzing a Maven project with SonarQube Analyzer is likely half your problem and a *whole lot* of extra work. Please try using the [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven), which should just pick up your code coverage automatically.

If that still doesn't work, double check the analysis log to make sure the coverage reports are being picked up.

Comment: I think the problem is because of multi module maven project.It's analyzing root project,not the child modules.Here I'm sharing my sonar-project.properties filePlease help me .